# Spectron test sequential actions

Tags: javascript, testing, electron, spectron

I am testing electron application with spectron. I have found in documentation examples on how to get number of windows and it is quite trivial. But what I am looking is how to check the state of one element after I have click on another element. Here I am trying to check if application is visible after I have minimized it. But this test always pass, for true and for false.

```
     it('should minimize the application', () => {
        return this.app.client.click('.minimize').then(() => {
          this.app.client.browserWindow.isVisible().then((isVisible) => {
            expect(isVisible).to.be.equal(true);
          });
        });
      })
```

I am using mocha with chai asserts.

Please advise on how can I check if application ( or particular element is visible ) after I have clicked on another element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `return` the results of your callback functions.

```
it('should minimize the application', () => {
  return this.app.client.click('.minimize').then(() => {
    return this.app.client.browserWindow.isVisible().then((isVisible) => {
      return expect(isVisible).to.be.equal(true);
    });
  });
});
```

Alternatively, drop the wrapping curly braces, and the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) will return the result automatically.

```
it('should minimize the application', () =>
  this.app.client.click('.minimize').then(() => 
    this.app.client.browserWindow.isVisible().then((isVisible) => 
      expect(isVisible).to.be.equal(true);
    );
  );
);
```

I don't think that's quite as readable, but that might just be me.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain your **promises**

I use like this

`Return this.app.client.click('.minimize').browserWindow.isVisible().should.be.equal(true)`